# splide js pauseOn Hover option don't have effect

Tags: javascript, splidejs

I'm using splide js to create a sliding carousel, but the option `pauseOnHover` is not working. Because if you hover over the slider, it will stop sliding even I already set the option to be false `pauseOnHover: false,`.

```js
const splide = new Splide('.splide', {
   type: 'loop',
   pauseOnHover: false,
   autoScroll: {
      speed: 2,
   }
});

splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
```

```html
<section class="splide" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example">
  <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.1/dist/css/splide.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.1/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll@0.4.2/dist/js/splide-extension-auto-scroll.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put your `pauseOnHover` inside `autoScroll: {}` to get what you want like so:

```js
const splide = new Splide('.splide', {
   type: 'loop',
   autoScroll: {
      speed: 2,
      pauseOnHover: false,
   }
});

splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
```

```html
<section class="splide" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example">
  <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.1/dist/css/splide.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.0.1/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll@0.4.2/dist/js/splide-extension-auto-scroll.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helped.